# Issue with creating List View with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I am having an issue creating a ListView with my data. The code to produce it is:

```
protected void onPostExecute(DtoProjectListItem[] result) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    // DtoProjectListItem[] Adapter for ListView
    ArrayAdapter<DtoProjectListItem> projects_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DtoProjectListItem>(
            ProjectListActivity.this,
            R.layout.activity_project_list_item, 
            R.id.tvProjectName, 
            result
    );

    ListView lvProjects = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_project_list);
    lvProjects.setAdapter(projects_adapter);
```

}

The error I get is:

```
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cad930)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.my.cihub.ProjectListActivity$GetDataAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ProjectListActivity.java:173)
    at org.my.cihub.ProjectListActivity$GetDataAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ProjectListActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 20:31:03.386: I/Process(21412): Sending signal. PID: 21412 SIG: 9
```

Line 173 is:

```
lvProjects.setAdapter(projects_adapter);
```

Can somebody help me figure this out?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in this line

```
ListView lvProjects = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_project_list);
```

it should be like this

```
ListView lvProjects = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_id);
```

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem, looking at the docs, one of the constructors shows: `public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`. Where `int resource` is `The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.`

Comment: I am talking about `ListView`... adapter definition is more then ok :)

Comment: That fixed the error but now I have a different error. But thank you for helping me to progress.

Comment: I'll post a different question for the next error if I can't figure it out.